# Write WMA tags in PHP

Tags: php, wma, getid3

I use [GetID3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/) to read and write tags on MP3 files.
That library can read, but not write WMA metadata.
Any suggestions for a library, extension or other relatively straightforward way edit WMA metadata.

Answer (score 2):

WMA files are Windows Media Audio compressed audio stored in an ASF container.  I found this site that claims to support reading and writing metadata in ASF files -- http://code.google.com/p/php-reader/wiki/ASF

Comment: That looks interesting. I will try it out before I mark this as the answer.